# Wrong result with symbolic calculation in Mathematica

Tags: bugs, series-expansion

I am looking at the expansion of a time series
`Series [`$\left(\sum_{s=1}^\infty\frac{r}{(1+k)^s}x^{s+1}\right)^{-1}$`{x, 0, 2}` and I get a result like

```
1 + (r x^2)/(1 + k) + SeriesData[x, 0, {}, 0, 3, 1]
```

If I now simplify the above term first, I get $\frac{1}{1-\frac{x^2 r}{1+k-x}}$. Running the Series-command on the invers of this term, i.e., `Series[1-(x^2 r)/(1 + k - x)` gives me a different answer then the one above. This seems to be a bug or am I making a mistake here?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You write "Running the Series-command on the inverse of this term ..."  but that term is already the inverse you want to run the Series-command on.

[image]